# Architecture for iOS and Android Project  using web view loading html and js from server (singe code base)

Tags: android, ios, architecture, webview

We have recently started a Hybrid project(?) to work on iOS as well as Android with the following specifications:

Html pages, Javascript file, Jquery based libraries files and resource files (Images) are hosted on a server.
The hybrid code (iOS or android) loads the html pages in the web view and the page navigation and event handling is completely like any normal html and js based website. We have taken care of CORS for AJAX web service calls. The data is basically stored as local storage(browser's support).

Most of the data that is viewed by the user is live from web service calls, Except some of the images captured using camera which will be stored locally in the application sandbox. (For camera invocation, we have written native code.)

Why the architecture is planned in this way ?
One of the reasons -  Any modification in the application will be handled right from the server as I mentioned that all the html and js files are centrally located on the server, Ofcourse also to skip the Apple's App submission process).

Now I am not really sure if there might be any issues with this kind of application - the issues might be because 1. Whether Apple accepts such apps ? 2. Maintenance of the Project 3. Any critics on the architectural design of the App.

I am one small developer in this project, I have these questions for you. Apologize me if I haven't put my doubts in appropriate way. Your critics and answers/tips are most welcome. Thanks..

Comment: As a user, I absolutely hate html "apps". They never follow the UI guidelines of the platforms they support so they look and feel very weird. On Android, they tend to not work very well with multi-tasking and the back button and they never integrate with the more advanced capabilities of the system such as intents and account management.

Answer (score 0):

You should use native code if possible, the performance of HTML5 apps is not very good when compared to the native apps plus the things that you can do with native apps are just worth it. Although Apple shouldn't have any problems with your apps. But As Wesley said they never really follow that consistency of the platform so they just look out of the place. Even in native apps, you might still be able to control simple aspects of your app like theme etc from a server, you just need to think ahead.

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. But in this architecture, we have a single code base which is a good advantage right ?